# How to cast List<Subinterface> to List<SuperInterface>?

Tags: java, list, collections, casting

Consider the following code, where `Feline` and `Animal` are interfaces and  `Feline extends Animal`.

```
List<Feline> miaus = foo.retrieveMiaus();
List<Animal> animals = xxxx;
bar.pet(animals);
```

What is the best way to cast miaus to animals - i.e the `xxxx`?

One way is to:

```
 List<Animal> animals = (List<Animal>) (List<?>)miaus;
```

But it has unchecked casts - and it downright looks ugly.

One can also iterate over `miaus` and populate the animals by casting each `Feline` to `Animal`, but this isn't ideal either.

Is there any cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Can you share the actual `Animal` and `Feline` code?

Comment: There is no clean way because a `List<Feline>` is not a `List<Animal>`.

Comment: `List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>(miaus);` - it's not casting, it's constructing a new list of the right type.

Comment: @akortex I think the simplest "proof of concept" is just empty interfaces `Animal` and `Feline`.

Comment: @AndyTurner's answer compiles but has the same unparameterised warning (1/2)

Comment: Probably because of what @luk2302 points out (2/2)

Comment: @mmalmeida nope, no warnings there. The [`ArrayList<E>` copy constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)) accepts a `Collection<? extends E>` as the parameter: that is, you can construct an `ArrayList<Animal>` from a `List<Feline>`.

Comment: `List<Animal> animals = Collections.unmodifiableList(miaus);` works without warnings and without copying, because the created view does not allow modifications, so you can't insert a wrong `Animal` into `animals`.